# On Press Tab append input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I working in an attendance register where I have a table with a date on which the user should enter the work duration like 1 or 1.5 or 2 which means 1 as a full day, 1.5 as one and half day and so on.

The Problem which I am facing is I have javascript where I have given on click to append the input field. but what I am looking for is whenever the user press tab it should go to the next input field.

Please take a look at the screenshot of the layout.

[image: Screenshot of the layout]

Here is javascript code :

```
$(function () { 
        $("td").on("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tdID = $(this).attr("id");
        var $input = $("<input>", {
        value: $this.text(),
        type: "text",
        style: "width:40px",
        id:"myInput",
        blur: function() { 
        $this.text(this.value);
        saveEidatedData(tdID);
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
     if ((e.which === 13)&&(e.which === 9)) $input.blur();
    },
      }).appendTo( $this.empty() ).focus();
  });
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", shows you are not included jquery reference in your page. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes. The code is working fine. But the only problem is it is going to next row when I am clicking I want when I press tab then also it should go.

Comment: `Tab` is the default functionality of markup, you need to use [tabindex](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/27-tabindex.html)

Comment: Can you please write the answer what changes is required

Comment: You want user to click to create input, then tab to append then create next input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing it in JavaScript, you should populate the day with the text box having attribute of `tabindex` starting from some number and increment it to +1 for each row it should be start from where the last row `tabindex` ended.

if you doing it in JavaScript it would take extra time to make it work also you need to place extra checks.

like below example click on the first field and press `tab` it will move to the next input field.

To do as per my suggestion, it helps you to update time easily for specific day, as well as to populate the day's from array / object data type.

```html
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" tabindex="1" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" tabindex="2" value="2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" tabindex="3" value="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" tabindex="4" value="4" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" tabindex="5" value="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" tabindex="6" value="6" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Problem is All the data is dynamic. So that won't be possible

Comment: there would be no problem if you create such scenario whenever the form is submit make ajax call or reload the page and then populate the markup with default input for their timelogs. and update  it for specific person on specific day because i don't see any button to save the data of each day so in that case there would be ajax for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this? You may also use arrow keys, to remove the arrow key functionality just delete it from the 'arr' array

```js
var sftDown = false;
$(document).on({
 keydown: function(e) {
   //37 - 40 = arrows keys
    //13 = enter
    //9 = tab ( should auto move with tab)
   var arr = [9,13,37,38,39,40];
    if ( e.which == 16 ) sftDown = true;
    
   if ( $.inArray(e.which, arr) !== -1 ) {
      var main = $(this).closest('#table');
      var rows = main.find('tr');
      var cells = main.find('input[type="text"]');
      var downAmount = cells.length/rows.length;
      var move = 1;
      
      switch (e.which) {
       case 9:
         move = 0;
        break;
        case 40:
        case 13:
         move = downAmount;
        break;
        case 38:
         move = downAmount * -1;
        break;
        case 37:
         move *= -1;
        break;
      }
      
      if ( sftDown ) move *= -1;
   
      var i = cells.index(this) + move;
     if ( i >= cells.length ) i %= cells.length;
      if ( i < 0 ) i = cells.length + i;
     cells[i].focus();
      
    }
   
    
  },
  keyup: function(e) {
   if ( e.which == 16 ) sftDown = false;
  }
},'#table input[type="text"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```